# Random Image Issue with Bitnami Joomla

Tags: joomla, bitnami

I have changed my joomla! application to run at / (root) instead of /joomla/ by:

> ./bnconfig --appurl /

Everything works fine, except a Random Image Module, which no longer displays images. 
Checking the html source, the link of the pictures looks like:

> //folders/filename.jpg

which seems to be wrong.

Any hints how to influence that the src in the html is:

> /folders/filename.jpg

like in case of other simple pictures displayed correctly.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've just tested on a clean install and it seems working for me.

Maybe just forgot to configure the module? This link have detailed information on how to configure the module.

Could you provide more information about the issue? Things like Joomla version, module version and how do you installed Joomla (Installer, container, AWS , ...)

Comment: It is Joomla version, 3.6.2. through Bitnami stack. The module is configured.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that changing the path of the pictures from absolute:

> /opt/joomla-3.6.2-1/apps/joomla/htdocs/images/thumbnails

to relative

> images/thumbnails

solves the issue.